# How to get answers of dynamically generated arraylist of images name

Tags: android

i have to create simple app in which i have number of images and there answers.

i.e "How many triangles do you see in the picture". One image will be shown and there will be ExitView to enter the answer in it.

Each time images will be shown randomly and not repeated. i have done using ArrayList.

But the problem is how to know Answers of randomly List of images.

Any Guide or idea to approach it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use hashmap with image id as a key and answer as value.